# CodeIgniter button onclick(), page redirect issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am very new to CodeIgniter.

I have created the controller as bellow.

```
<?php
    class Search_Student_Ctrl extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            //redirect('student_home');
            $this->load->view('student_home', null);
        }
    }
?>
```

My view as bellow,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <h1>Student Management System</h1>

    <button onclick="location.href='<?php echo base_url();?>Search_Student_Ctrl/index'">Search Student</button>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the button I am getting bellow error.

***The requested URL /sms/Student_Home_Ctrl/index was not found on this server.***

Note: I have added bellow line in autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: 1)  Have you read the CodeIgniter documentation?  2)  Have you taken the time to do the tutorial in the CI documentation?  3)  `index.php` should be part of the URL unless you're using something like `.htaccess` to suppress it.  4) Have you checked your `routes.php` file to see if something is over-riding this.

Comment: I modified .htaccess to suppress index.php. I went through the documentation. Share your idea if you know.

Comment: I already did... item #4.  Otherwise, you don't have enough information in the question in order for anyone to answer this.  In other words, your code, as posted above, works for me.

Comment: Try to rename your controller filename to `search.php`, Controller Name to `Search` and `echo base_url('search');`.

Answer (score 1):

what happens when you just go to the url in your browser?
http://yourdomain.com/sms/Student_Home_Ctrl/index

Are you still getting the requested url was not found?
Try:
http://yourdomain.com/index.php/sms/Student_Home_Ctrl/index

Did you follow the right steps to remove index.php?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a few reasons for it:

1. it might be because you are working on a local environment and
   didn't set a host in the hosts file so the base_url cannot be found by Codeigniter (see 3. or set a local host)
2. you didn't loaded the Helper: `$this->load->helper('url');`
3. if all of the above still don't work you should configure the base_url in your config.php: `$config['base_url'] = '';`

Comment: Codeigniter should be able to detect your BASE_URL, in case you are working on a local enviornment and accessing the enviroment using IP/localhost for example. it might not return any url. you can add "virtualhost" to your local enviornment. for example to access your local enviorment using url like: `local.example.com`
you could read more about how to set virtualhost here (its for Ubuntu and Apache but the concept is the same): https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: about the 3rd point if you don't want to create a virtualhost you could just explictly define your base url in the Config.php file for example: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost';`

Answer (score 0):

Search_Student_Ctrl/index'">Search Student

Change above lines to

```
<button onclick="location.href='<?php echo site_url('Search_Student_Ctrl/index');?>'">Search Student</button>
```

For calling controllers from view you have to use **site_url()** instead of **base_url()**

Answer (score 0):

- No need to add index function url. by default controller get index function

  Search_Student_Ctrl'">Search Student
- Please also check your .htaccess file working or not.
- You have removed index.php in url? If yes then check rewrite rule is working on your server.
- In codeIgniter 3 Class is always start with capital letter for controller ass well ass models.